# I want apply different intents as a result of different activities. How can I do so?

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class demoProject1 extends Activity {
    int i;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String lv_arr[]={"Image Excercise","Audio Play","Video Play","ListView Advanced Excercise","Task Bar Implementation","Map Excercise"};

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv;

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(demoProject1.this,R.layout.newlist,lv_arr) );
        lv.setDividerHeight(2);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {                         

                Intent intent = new Intent(demoProject1.this,ImageExercise.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                //Intent intent1 = new Intent(demoProject1.this,AudioPlay.class);
                //startActivity(intent1);   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I want is the listview being displayed and when a view is clicked a new page opens.  How can I apply Switch case to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
switch (position) {
    case 0: //Image Excercise
        Intent intent = new Intent(demoProject1.this,ImageExercise.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
        break;
    case 1://Audio Play
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(demoProject1.this,AudioPlay.class);
        startActivity(intent1);  
    default:
        break;
    }
```